# When a large company wants to issue bonds, it contracts with number of banks and consulting firms, why does it need all that?

Tags: bonds

When a large company wants to issue bonds, it contracts with number of banks and consulting firms, why does it need all that ? is this issue that complicated ?

Comment: Question #1 Because banks are expert and loaning huge sums of money; widget manufacturers aren't.  Question #2: Yes; lots of rules and regulations to follow, lots of time and effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is this issue that complicated ?

Yes - it certainly is.  Here's just some reasons off the top of my head:

- Banks (and auditors) add *independent legitimacy* to an offering by making sure that the company is representing its financials accurately through an underwriting process.
- Companies are good at *their business*, but most companies aren't specialists in corporate finance, laws, regulations, etc. that go into bond offerings.
- Banks have existing relationships with institutional investors to gauge interest in buying these bonds
- Banks understand the bond market well enough to know how to accurately price bonds before they're offered (to make sure the issuer sets the coupon right to get as close to par for the bonds as possible)

You might also ask why people use realtors to buy houses, or why they hire lawyers to go to court, or why companies use advertising firms, or...